# Python beautifulsoup parsing html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[image]

I tried to get the value in the last html code "#4.52" using code below but it returns nothing.. is it because it has "#" before the 4.52?? is there any ways to get the value instead??

```
import bs4
import requests
import urllib
import urllib.request


url = "https://lolchess.gg/profile/kr/%EB%8F%99%EB%B3%B4%EC%A0%84%EB%A0%A5"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


tier1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "profile__tier"})
averagerank1 = tier1.find("div", {"class": "col-6 profile__tier__avg_rank"})
averagerank2 = averagerank1.find("span", {"class": "profile__tier__stat__value float-right"})
print(averagerank2.text)
```

Comment: Your screenshot looks like the DOM view of the browser. It does not represent the HTML source code. Looks at the real source code of the page.

Comment: Oh.. i just saw the real HTML source code and there was nothing. is it possible?? nothing on the HTML and appear in DOM view?

Comment: Thx. that was exactly what i was searching for.